# What is SKNode "origin"?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Docs for `SKPhysicsBody` `bodyWithCircleOfRadius:` says:

> Creates a circular physics body centered on the owning node’s **origin**.

So is origin a node position? Couldnt find it anywere.

Comment: origin == node.position

Comment: yep, thanks :) confirmed with simple app

Answer (score 4):

> So is origin a node position?

The *origin* is the point with coordinates (0, 0) in a given coordinate system. However, you typically deal with a number of different coordinate systems when working with computer graphics, and each one has its own origin. For example, every view in a view hierarchy has its own coordinate system. So, you need some context to know exactly which one you're talking about.

From the [SKNode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> Every node in a node tree provides a coordinate system to its
>   children. After a child is added to the node tree, it is positioned
>   inside its parent’s coordinate system by setting its position
>   properties.

You also commented:

> Im confused becouse 'origin' also is mention in SKScene docs, and its different than frames origin

`SKScene` is a subclass of `SKNode`, and so it's also the case that every scene provides a coordinate system. This isn't surprising -- a scene is just the root node in a tree of nodes.

Don't confuse the `origin` of a node's `frame` with the origin of the node's own coordinate system. A `CGRect` is defined by two things: a *CGPoint* called `origin`, and a *CGSize* called `size`. A node's `frame` is the rectangle that defines the node's bounds *in the coordinate system of the parent* node. The node's origin might happen to be at the same place as it's frame's `origin`, but they're not the same thing. For example, the origin of a scene is at it's `anchorPoint` -- that is, the `anchorPoint` property of a scene indicates some point in the view that contains the scene, and that point has coordinates (0, 0) in the scene. Neither of these have anything to do with the `frame` or `frame.origin`.

Comment: so accumulationg all together: node's origin is the point in its parent's coordinate system, and its (0,0) in node's own coordinate system. It happens that node's position is the same point, but its nowhere written in docs for SKNode, SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 1):

Origin is *normally* a point.  However, it is slightly confusing to speak of a SKNode's origin, because that is not a property of the SKNode in the same sense that it is a property of the SKNode's frame. If you do a keyword search in apples' sknode docs for the word 'origin' you will find it zero times. However, I agree with the consensus below that despite this lack of mention in the SKNode's docs, the origin of a node is more likely to refer to its position than to its frame's origin. So while you would get the SKNode's frame's origin's x and y values like this:

```
node.frame.origin.x
node.frame.origin.y
```

That does not necessarily describe the node's origin. I hope I have made this answer more accurate and less confusing :)

Comment: Im confused becouse 'origin' also is mention in SKScene docs, and its different than frames origin: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Comment: It looks like for SKScene:SKnode,  origin coresponds to anchor point which can be different then frames origin.

Comment: nope, origin is simply the node's position. Note that anchorpoint is merely a texture drawing offset, and only 3 nodes have an anchorPoint (scene, sprite, video)